# Drupal Commons add automation using Workflow modules to solve the problem of Wiki/Article Publishing for End users

Tags: 7, workbench

I have a Drupal Commons Profile and I have setting up the following modules to my drupal commons site.

**Workbench**

1. Workbench Access
2. Workbench Moderator

Configure the **Taxonomy** and set it to "**Section**"

**My Workflow**

1. Content Creators
2. Content Publishers

Article Content Type:
Publishing Options: Disabled
Enabled Moderator Options to "Drafts"

**Created two Roles**

- Content Creator ( Content Creators )
- Channel Manager ( Content Publishers )

**Set permissions to Each Role**

First I logged in as Content Creator

```
My Workbench->Create Content->Article->Add New Article
Set Moderator: "Needs Review"
```

and `Save article`.

**Issues:**

After logged in as *Publishers account*.
Go to

```
My Workbench->Needs Review
```

But there is no any content will be appear.

***But If i logged in as Administrator I will show the same there?***

Can anyone let me know what was the issue I am facing.
any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

your subject is quite different than the question you ask. If its just a permission issue then you need to check under roles and permission. Sometime we cannot give all rights required to for mod or data entry access, so best is to copy administrator role and remove all critical permission and assign only what you want to give (to specific piece of content).

Btw, workbench is only used for permissions and not for the work flow. Its a like creating a working space for certain set of people (work bench) with adequate permissions, that's it.

If your question is regarding your subject of how to create workflow, then look at maestro module https://drupal.org/project/maestro to create GUI based logical workflow with great level of approvals, check point and notification options.

I researched Maestro week back for my friend and worked for a short while.

Comment: Actually I would like to create Publishing workflow Content Creator will add new content, Publisher Review or Publish the Content.

Comment: Maestro is good enough over the workbench module?

Comment: What are the Maestro modules are available for Drupal Commons?